# How to clear cookies in ChromeCustomTabs?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm implementing login to application via ChromeCustomTabs. I don't need to keep the session -  vice versa, I need to ask user for login on every launch of app. How can I clear the cookies of ChromeCustomTabs?

Answer (score 3):

The one of the main ideas of `CromeCustomTabs` are shared cookies with `Chrome` browser, so the user will be able easily to use its "saved data" (credentials, etc.) in opened from your application tab. It means that you **cannot clear cookies** that are used by `ChromeCustomTab`.

If you want to have more control of the cookies in particular, you should consider using `WebView` instead.