# How to clear cookies from Custom Tabs Android

Tags: android, cookies, chrome-custom-tabs, appauth, android-customtabs

I've implemented SSO using the App Auth library.  Part of the functionality of our app is when the user is logged in via App auth the cookies are shared to Custom Tabs in order for users to access logged in user content.  However, when the user logs out from the app and we end our auth session with the end session request,  I then want to be able to clear the cookies from the Custom Tabs as we don't want logged out users to access that logged in user content.

So in short we require the use of Custom Tabs to allow cookie sharing from the login, however we need to remove those cookies when the auth session is finished.

I have tried  `CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies()` but unfortunately that doesn't do anything.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

TIA

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing same issue.

Comment: @abalta Apparently we can't, this answer explains more https://stackoverflow.com/a/50450236/5046642